# Get full path of current file with php

Tags: php, xml

I'm working on index.php file which located in /folder1/folder2/folder3/index.php and contains some php code as below:

```
<?php 
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/the/filename.php'; 
$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); 
echo $root->subroot[0]->data->title; 
?>
```

The **filename.php** doesn't change name or extension. But, **folders and subfolders** that lead to filename.php carry different names depending on current circumstances.

For example, in an instance folders are named as /a1/a2/a3/filename.php and in another instance named as /b1/b2/b3/filename.php. Filename.php carries the same name in all instances but inside contains different data.

If that helps, the filename.php structured below:

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<'XML'
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<root>
 <subroot>
  <data>
   <title>
    -- some text here --
   </title>
  </data>
 </subroot>
</root>
XML;
?>
```

Since folders and subfolders are already created and their names are known, I want (if that is possible) to code the /path/to/the/ so it won't be necessary for the user to type the corresponded path each time creates a new index.php file. I try something like this:

```
<?php 
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].['__DIR__']'filename.php'; 
$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); 
echo $root->subroot[0]->data->title; 
?>
```

...and:

```
<?php 
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].['REQUEST_URI']'filename.php'; 
$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); 
echo $root->subroot[0]->data->title; 
?>
```

...but both don't work. Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
 __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'filename.php';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php